# repeating php in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I have the following code and was wondering if its possible to make the PHP part repeat so the javascript var is kept upto date even if a new row has been add to the table?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var total_rows = [];
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
    $total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($total);
 ?> 
var total_rows = "<?php echo $num_rows ; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Repeat.... where?  When?

Comment: PHP: Server side, JavaScript: Client side. Once the data leaves the server there is no PHP anymore.

Comment: I think you need to read up on AJAX

Comment: Could you add an example of desired output?

Comment: you would have to move the php part to a separate script and use AJAX to access it within your javascript

Comment: i updated my original post if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, because PHP is server side only, and has finished executing by the time your JS is executed.

While you *could* check it without reloading the page using AJAX, I would question whether what you are doing is useful anyway - the client should not care about the *number* of rows in a table as a general rule - the only real exception being if you are making a database management page, and even then it's usefulness is debatable. If you need to update/delete a row from client input, all you need is the ID of the row, and if you are adding one you should let the database generate a row ID for you with an auto-incrementing primary key.

I suspect you would be better looking at your application's implementation as whole if you have reach a point where you feel you need this information at the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to update parts of your page without reloading the entire page. You should look into that. A good tutorial to start will be http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp.

Repeating the PHP code in HTML itself is not possible, because the PHP code is not available in the HTML page. The HTML page is the result of executing a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use AJAX to hit a file which does the PHP select and returns the desired row.

Answer (score -2):

You would have to refresh your query to get the latest count, so I would do something like this. this example uses jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
function get_updated_rows(){       
    $.get('count.php', function(data) {
        var total_rows = data;
    }) 
    return total_rows;    
}
```

You count.php file would contain the php:

```
 <?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
           $total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
           $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($total); 
           echo $num_rows;
 ?>
```

then when you need the updated count, just use your function: get_updated_rows();

Comment: Just no. PHP is server side, you can't just execute from JS like this. Your function will always return the value that was generated when the page was loaded.